# Escape SQL Full Text Conditional Keywords

Tags: sql, full-text-search

Can anyone tell me how to have keywords like "AND" and "OR" in the actual search query itself and not get an error? For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS(MyColumn, 'This and')
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Syntax error near 'and' in the full-text search condition 'This and'
```

Perfectly understandable why there is an error, but how do I ignore the keyword and just have the "and" as part of the search phrase?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is about MS SQL, then I think you will have to write

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS(MyColumn, '"This and"')
```

Note the double quotes